# How to solve TIFFOpen Error Popup in RStudio?

Tags: r, plot, jpeg, tiff

I am running spThin from the package "spThin" in RStudio
I am trying to save the plot generated from plotThin function

Following is my code after the spThin function:

```
tiff(file = paste(n, "plotThin2.tiff", sep = "_"))
plotThin(ca.thin, which = 2)
dev.off()
```

However, I get `/n_plotThin2.tiff: Cannot Open.`
I don't think it is the issue with my code as I went the code another 2 computers without problem but only this computer
If I switched from tiff to `jpeg()`
I get Error during wrapup: unable to start `jpeg()` device
I am running R 3.6.2

Can someone help please. Thank you

Comment: I had a similar error with tiff because I was pointing to output directory that did not exist.